# PCF auto drop and start application in non-buisness hours

Tags: pcf, pcfdev, appcfg, httpcfg.exe

I am new to pcf and working on a task for drop all instances on a particular time. 
I need drop all apps instances during non business hours and bring it back before start of business hours?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using App Autoscaler where you can automatically increase and decrease instances based on either of following-

1. No of Http request (Http Throughput).
2. CPU utilization.
3. Http latency.

This will automatically drop the instances during off hours and increases when no of request start to increase i.e. in business hours.

You could also test this by doing stress testing using tools like jitter which helps you to increase and decrease the load artificially on your app.